# How to pass Python variable into bash commands?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I've seen some answers about `subprocess.call` and `popen`, but I have a list of commands and I think it's not a good idea to have multiple calls or etc. Also I don't want to have a separate `script.sh` with these commands.

My code looks like

```
bash_code=r'''
echo "/common_home/{context['nickname']}  /tmp/back/{context['nickname']}  none bind 0 0" | sudo tee --append /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir /tmp/{context['nickname']}  /tmp/back/{context['nickname']}
'''
subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', bash_code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it has much more line with `{context['nickname']}` and I don't know best way how to parse this variable into bash commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a so-called "[f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-f-string)" to replace the variable references with their values.

```
context = {'nickname': 'foobar'}

bash_code = f'''
echo "/common_home/{context['nickname']}  /tmp/back/{context['nickname']}  none bind 0 0" | sudo tee --append /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir /tmp/{context['nickname']}  /tmp/back/{context['nickname']}
'''

print(bash_code)
subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', bash_code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Value printed:

```
echo "/common_home/foobar  /tmp/back/foobar  none bind 0 0" | sudo tee --append /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir /tmp/foobar  /tmp/back/foobar
```

Comment: I must downvote this because of the security vulnerability. You know how dangerous SQL injections are? This is the shell equivalent. It's dangerous because the substitutions aren't escaped properly. A security warning would be advisable; or better than a warning, a safe solution that doesn't dynamically create shell commands.